# How to properly handle & control Errors in Angular and Web API - 2

Tags: angular, web, error-handling, webapi2

I am wondering how to properly handle and control errors in Angular & Web api,
on some tutorial I saw that errors are handled in a component and not in a service which is fetching data.. and basically both backend and angular/clients erros are handled in a component like this:

[image]

I'm wondering how is possible that he handles both backend and frontend errors in a component? So does that mean I DON'T NEED TRY/CATCH IN A WEB API ? this should handle it also ?

I'm confused here, please explain me this example...

And I thought error handler should be added in a `service.ts` - in this example `PeopleService`, while `PeopleService` looks like this:

[image]

So I'm confused about this:

> Shouldn't there be logic in a service.ts which would handle errors?
>
> Shouldn't I wrote try/catch in a WebApi, how come backend errors are
>   handled here?

Thanks for help guys
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In your example a backend error is something like the server responded with 404 (not found). For example you requested a specific person by id and the server did not find any person related to that id so it returns a response with 404. This way the client will know that the person the user is trying to find does not exist.

> Shouldn't there be logic in a service.ts which would handle errors?

From [Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details):

> Error inspection, interpretation, and resolution is something you want to do in the service, not in the component.

Errors are encapsulated in an `ErrorObservable` in the service not the component.

then in your component you would do something like:

```
service.subscribe(
   result => this.result = result,
   error => console.log(error)
);
```

> Shouldn't I wrote try/catch in a WebApi, how come backend errors are handled here?

You are not handling errors that occur in the backend. You are handling errors returned from the server response. For example: if there is an null reference error in your backend handling the error like your example will not save your server from crashing.

The backend is a process of its own. It has its own error handlers. The client code (angular) runs in the user's browser.

You could see the guide on [angular site](https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling) for more on this.

Comment: so you advice is to handle erros in a component that is invoking a service?

Comment: My original answer is wrong. I edited my answer. Been out of touch lately sorry about that :)